# Ruby language feature of Set[1,2,3]

Tags: ruby, initialization, language-features

In Ruby, a set can be initialized by Set[1,2,3]
So can an array: Array[1,2,3]

Is it possible to write some code to do the same thing to my own classes?
Or it's just a language feature for only a few built-in classes?

Comment: As a side note, `Array[1, 2, 3]` will call `Array.[]`, but `Array [1, 2, 3]` (with a space after the `y`) will call `Kernel#Array`.

Comment: Avdi Grimm describes methods like `Kernel#Array` as "conversion functions" in [this comment](http://blog.mojotech.com/post/38317154050#comment-746181678).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ruby, `foo[bar, baz]` is just syntactic sugar for `foo.[](bar, baz)`. All you need is a method named `[]`.

By the way: you just need to look at the documentation, e.g. for [`Set`](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-c-5B-5D):

> ## `[](*ary)`
>
> Creates a new set containing the given objects.

That's the documentation right there.

Basically, all you need is

```
class Foo
  def self.[](*args, &block)
    new(*args, &block)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, since `[]` and `[]=` are just methods, they can be overridden.

You could try something like this:

```
class MyArray
  attr_accessor :data

  def self.[](*values)
    obj = MyArray.new
    obj.data = values
    return obj
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class X
  attr_accessor :contents

  def self.[](*x)
    obj = self.new
    obj.contents = x
    obj
  end
end
```